# Is there a way to change the Photoshop Alt + Right-click-drag brush size hotkey?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Since CS5, we can use Alt + Right-click-drag(I'm currently using CS6 on win) to change brush size and opacity. But it is not good enough for a tablet pen. While I release the right-click button on my pen, it always shakes a lit bit, when I need a precise brush size this shake is killing me. So is there a way to change this hotkey I can't find it in the preference setting.

I'm trying to find a way to make it works like Painter/OpenCanvas.

Comment: [You can change brush size via hotkey.](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2012/07/changing-the-brush-size-and-hardness-in-photoshop-cs6.html) Although, if it really needs to be that precise, maybe just right click the document and set the size you want your brush to be.

Comment: I know how to change brush size by hotkeys, that's why I post a question here. Alt + Right-click-drag is technically a hotkey combination, but it's not in the preference setting. There might be a way to customize it. I just can't find anything about it.

Comment: There is no setting that would affect this. Your only hope is to get around it somehow.

Comment: Maybe some alternative input device or voice command has a place just here. Devices designed to help disabled people are pricey but simple switches or switchboards for sending preprogrammed typings are available. Search for example *USB foot switch* and explore voice command possiblities.

Comment: @user287001 some tablets have keys that you can bind to shortcuts, thus having a shortcut is important. Also your second hand is free to use a keyboard in some tablet configurations.

Answer (score 2):

If moving a hand to the keyboard doesn't interrupt your workflow too much, the bracket keys can be used to increase and decrease the brush size and hardness pretty effectively. To be fair, I'm left handed so this fits into my workflow quite naturally.

[ = decrease brush size 
{ = decrease brush hardness 
] = increase brush size 
} = increase brush hardness

Comment: Thank you for replying.
If we compare PS with Painter/OpenCanvas, the bracket keys are far from effective. And I knew this difference a decade ago.

Comment: My apologies, your initial inquiry did not mention Painter or Open Canvas.

Comment: My bad, edited.